# Resume learning in Caffe using different GPUs

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, snapshot, resume, training-data

I wanna ask something about resuming learning in Caffe. The case is like this:

1. At the first time training, i utilize four GPUs (0,1,2,3) to train image for 200000 iterations and save the snapshot, let's say, every 50000 iterations.
2. Then, i stop the learning at the 100000th iterations.
3. Then i wanna resume it again from 100000th snapshot model.

My question is, do we need to resume learning using the same GPUs (0,1,2,3) or we can just use other arbitrary GPU (let's say just using two GPUs (0 and 3) only for this resume)? I ask this because recently i can't resume the learning when using different number of GPUs but works well when using same GPUs

Comment: What's the problem when you resume the learning when using different number of GPUs?

Comment: hi @DaleSong, the problem is resume learning was aborted. You can see the details below:

Comment: `*** Aborted at 1473325340 (unix time) try "date -d @1473325340" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7f2f8a6d2677 (unknown)
*** SIGSEGV (@0x30338000) received by PID 3754 (TID 0x7f2f8ce00a40) from PID 808681472; stack trace: ***
   @     0x7f2f8a5b7cb0 (unknown)
   @     0x7f2f8a6d2677 (unknown)
   @     0x7f2f8c36335c std::vector<>::erase()
   @     0x7f2f8c3620e7 caffe::DevicePair::compute()
   @     0x7f2f8c36720c caffe::P2PSync<>::Prepare()
   @     0x7f2f8c36778c caffe::P2PSync<>::Run()
   @           0x40b02c train()
   @           0x40897c main`

Comment: Does it work well when you use any different compositions of GPUs  for training from scratch instead of resuming the training?